# Is it true Einstein doubted relativity near the end of his life?

Tags: relativity-theory, einstein

Heard he wrote a bunch of rambling thoughts near the end of his life and doubted his own theory of relativity...it was in Einstein: His Life and Universe by Walter Isaacson

Comment: Where have you heard it, and what exactly did Isaacson write? I looked through the last two chapters of his book, but did not find anything like that.

Comment: Maybe this refers to the "cosmological constant" ... which Einstein later called his "biggest blunder".

Comment: Hi,  when asking questions, please replace "I've heard" with a citation link so we can evaluate the source

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I doubt it. He renounced the cosmological constant from 1931 onward, not in the last years, and never returned to it, see [Investigating the legend of Einstein’s “biggest blunder”](https://physicstoday.scitation.org/do/10.1063/PT.6.3.20181030a/full/).

Answer (score 8):

No.

He opposed Quantum Mechanics from the beginning until death. He did it because its inherent non-determinism ("God does not gamble"). In his opinion, the cause of the non-determinism of the QM is that "it is not ready".

However, he worked on the further development of the GR until death. A possible direction was to describe also the electromagnetism as spacetime curvature. This makes highly unlikely that he had doubted it.